# NUnit test cases not executing with M1 macbook and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, apple-m1, visual-studio-2022

Recently added Visual Studio 2022 to M1 Macbook, so I tried to add new console app and NUnit class library project in this sample project

[image]

This `TDDSample.UnitTest` project's target framework is ".NET 6.0.6".

Everything is building successfully, but when I try to run this unit test project, it's showing the following error:

> Testhost process exited with error:
> Error: an assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (TDDSample.UnitTest.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'NUnit', version: '3.13.3'
> path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/nunit.framework.dll'
>
> Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
>
> Testhost process exited with error:
> Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (TDDSample.UnitTest.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'NUnit', version: '3.13.3'
> path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/nunit.framework.dll'.
>
> Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the unit test project and recreating the unit test project, issue able to fix, seems like some project cache problem [image]